# angular 2 testing w/router

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular2-routing, angular2-testing

I have a component and when a user logs in it routes to a url called `/dashboard` I am really struggling figuring out why I am getting the following error.

```
cannot read property 'args' of undefined
```

I have been following the official docs on testing with router found here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#routed-component
but it doesnt seem to help. Half my problem is I dont quite understand all the code in the doc. Here is my unit test for the route

```
 beforeEach(async(()=>{

      class AuthStub{
        private loggedin: boolean = false;
            login(){
              return this.loggedin = true;

            }
      };

      class RouterStub{
        navigateByUrl(url:string){return url;}
      }

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ HomePageContentComponent ],
      providers:[
        {provide: Auth, useClass:AuthStub},
        {provide: Router, useClass: RouterStub}
        ]
    })
    .compileComponents()
  }));

  beforeEach(()=>{

      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomePageContentComponent);
      comp = fixture.componentInstance;

      de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.loginbtn'));
      el = de.nativeElement;
      fixture.detectChanges();

    });

    it('Should log in and navigate to dashboard', inject([Router],(router:Router)=>{

      const spy = spyOn(router, 'navigateByUrl');

      el.click();

      const navArgs = spy.calls.first().args[0];

      expect(navArgs).toBe('/dashboard');

    }))      
});
```

So my question is what is this line of code doing...

```
const navArgs = spy.calls.first().args[0];
```

and how can I fix my problem?

**Service added**

```
@Injectable()
export class Auth { 
    lock = new Auth0Lock('fakefakefakefakefake', 'fake.auth0.com', {
         additionalSignUpFields: [{
            name: "address",                              
            placeholder: "enter your address"
        }],
        theme: {
            primaryColor:"#b3b3b3",
        },
         languageDictionary: {
            title: "FAKE"
        }
    });

    userProfile: any;

    constructor(private router: Router) {
        this.userProfile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));

        this.lock.on("authenticated", (authResult) => {
            localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);

            this.lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken, (error, profile) => {
                if (error) {

                    alert(error);
                    return;
                }

                profile.user_metadata = profile.user_metadata || {};
                localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
                this.userProfile = profile;
            });
            this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        });
    }

    public login(){
        this.lock.show();

    };

    public authenticated() {
        return tokenNotExpired();
    };

    public logout() {
        localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
        localStorage.removeItem('profile');
        this.router.navigate(['/logout']);
    };
}
```

Comment: @yurzui added my service to question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say you have the following component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'home-comp',
  template: `<button (click)="login()" class="loginbtn">Login</button>
  `
})
export class HomePageContentComponent {
  constructor(private auth: Auth, private router: Router) { }

  login() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl(`/dashboard`);
  }
}
```

In your test after replacing real `Router` with mocked version:

```
{ provide: Router, useClass: RouterStub }
```

Inside you case:

```
it('Should log in and navigate to dashboard', inject([Router],(router:Router)=>{
```

`router` will be instance of `RouterStub`.

then you spy on for `navigateByUrl` method to watching how many times it was called

```
const spy = spyOn(router, 'navigateByUrl');
```

so when you clicking on the `.loginbtn` button `router.navigateByUrl` is running (see above component) and `spy` incrementes `calls` with some information(for example, what was called the argument)

Finally in this line

```
const navArgs = spy.calls.first().args[0];
```

is expected that your `router.navigateByUrl` method was called at least once then is getting passed argument from the first call.

Here is working **[Live Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/wDo3rQaD9IKLc7cruA0k?p=preview)**

Possible you went wrong somewhere and your `router.navigateByUrl` isn't executed.

Comment: In response to this answer, for my case my navigation is fired from my Auth service, in the constructor after authentication is confirmed. So I would actually want to build this navigation test for the service and not the component calling the service?

Comment: Current mock for Auth service doesnt't consist calling of router.navigateByUrl. Can you share your real service?